# How to fix jest error "A 'describe' callback must not return a value"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a jest method which is defined as follows:

```
describe("Component", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        //set values for the test
        // subject is defined here
    });

    describe("isVisible", () => {
        context("status1", () => {
            it("returns boolean", () => {
                expect(subject.isVisible).toBe(true);
            });
        })
    });
});
```

isVisible method is defined as follows

```
@computed
get isVisible() {
    return this.shouldRender && this.inTransit;
}
```

When i run the test i am getting the following error

> **A "describe" callback must not return a value**

if I remove the context block

```
describe("isVisible", () => {
    it("return boolean", () => {
        expect(subject.isVisible).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

then the test runs successfully.

But I need status 1, status2 etc to be tested in separate contexts.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: And what is that function `context`? As far as I can see it's not defined as a [jest global](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api).

Comment: Please provide the code of `context` function.